# c# paste into textbox doesn't work at runtime

Tags: c#, textbox, desktop-application, paste

This is so basic I must be overlooking something obvious. I have a plain C# desktop application with a textbox. When I run it in VS 2012, I can paste text from the clipboard into the textbox. But when it is compiled and I run the exe, it does nothing when I try to paste text into it, either using Ctrl-V or the right click menu. I have no trouble typing into it. I don't have this problem with VB.Net applications.

Comment: re create the textbox and recompile. Or you could try changing the multiline property to true.

Comment: _Desktop application_ means a WPF or a WinForms application?

Comment: WinForms. I've been developing in VB.Net for years. I even do a fair amount of C#, but something this simple has me totally confused.

Comment: Textbox is multi-line; all other properties look normal. I created a 2nd textbox and it does the same. I then created a new form with a text box, and open it from the 1st form (on button click) and that form's textbox I can paste into. So there is a property of the original form that prevents you from pasting into its controls.

Comment: The form has a user defined control on it. If I remove the control, it works. What is confusing me is that I can paste into the textbox in the development environment, but not when running the exe. I'll go thru the control's code and see if I can find out how it does this and if I can prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this very non obvious problem. My error turned out to be my Virus scanner running in the background (Webroot). The moment i turned it off I was able to paste into my text boxes!

I havent been able to find a work around yet other than turning my virus scanner off.